# dockerfile COPY from previous build fails

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I'm using a [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds) within my dokcerfile according to docker docs:

```
FROM node:8 as build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn
COPY . ./
RUN REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8010 yarn build

FROM mhart/alpine-node:8
RUN yarn global add serve
WORKDIR /app
COPY —-from=build /usr/src/app/build .
#COPY ./build .
CMD serve -p 80 -s .
```

but I'm getting the following error

```
Step 8/9 : COPY —-from=build /usr/src/app .
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder527544225/—-from=build: no such file or directory
```

I also tried the index instead of the name:  `COPY —-from=0` but still same result.

if I skip first build, I manually kick the yarn build and I copy the build result into the single container

```
#COPY ./build .
```

it works fine...

```
Docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.09.1-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   19e2cf6
 Built:        Thu Dec  7 22:22:25 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.09.1-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   19e2cf6
 Built:        Thu Dec  7 22:28:28 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Comment: What version of Docker are you running?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have the wrong type of dash in your Dockerfile. Your line:

```
COPY —-from=build /usr/src/app/build .
```

is not the same as:

```
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build .
```

Comment: Well spotted :)

Comment: wow... great catch buddy! Thanks a lot... I was getting crazy

Comment: Wandering googler here. This didn't help me for my issue, but up-voting for the sheer amazingness of spotting that.